# How to calculate an exponential moving average with python faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, quantitative-finance

I am busy building backtesting software and I've run into a hiccup with creating the exponential moving average. I was successful in creating it using a for loop but it took about 20 seconds to run per symbol I want to test (too long).

I am trying to find a **faster** solution, if anyone has any suggestions.

My current code looks like this, but it does not produce the **correct** results.

```
def exponential_moving_average(df, period):
    # Create a copy of original dataframe to work with.
    dataframe = df.copy()

    dataframe['EMA'] = dataframe['Close'].ewm( span        = period,
                                               adjust      = False,
                                               min_periods = period,
                                               ignore_na   = True
                                               ).mean()

    return dataframe['EMA']
```

This method is in an Indicators class and the inputs take the following.

- `df` is the `Open, High, Low` and `Close` price per day as well as any other indicators that will be used for backtesting and
- `period` is the 'window' or number of days the exponential moving average must be calculated for.

Here is a snippet with the `df` values:

```
            symbol     Open     High      Low    Close  ATR     slow_ma
Date        
2010-01-03  EURUSD  1.43075  1.43369  1.43065  1.43247  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-04  EURUSD  1.43020  1.44560  1.42570  1.44120  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-05  EURUSD  1.44130  1.44840  1.43460  1.43650  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-06  EURUSD  1.43660  1.44350  1.42820  1.44060  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-07  EURUSD  1.44070  1.44470  1.42990  1.43070  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-08  EURUSD  1.43080  1.44380  1.42630  1.44160  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-10  EURUSD  1.44245  1.44252  1.44074  1.44110  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-11  EURUSD  1.44280  1.45560  1.44080  1.45120  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-12  EURUSD  1.45120  1.45450  1.44530  1.44840  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-13  EURUSD  1.44850  1.45790  1.44570  1.45100  NaN  1.442916   
2010-01-14  EURUSD  1.45090  1.45550  1.44460  1.44990  NaN  1.444186   
2010-01-15  EURUSD  1.45000  1.45110  1.43360  1.43790  NaN  1.443043   
2010-01-17  EURUSD  1.43597  1.43655  1.43445  1.43480  NaN  1.441544   
2010-01-18  EURUSD  1.43550  1.44000  1.43340  1.43830  NaN  1.440954   
2010-01-19  EURUSD  1.43820  1.44130  1.42520  1.42870  NaN  1.438726
```

Here is the expected outcome for `slow_ma` (10 day period)

```
            symbol     Open     High      Low    Close  ATR     slow_ma
Date        
2010-01-03  EURUSD  1.43075  1.43369  1.43065  1.43247  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-04  EURUSD  1.43020  1.44560  1.42570  1.44120  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-05  EURUSD  1.44130  1.44840  1.43460  1.43650  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-06  EURUSD  1.43660  1.44350  1.42820  1.44060  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-07  EURUSD  1.44070  1.44470  1.42990  1.43070  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-08  EURUSD  1.43080  1.44380  1.42630  1.44160  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-10  EURUSD  1.44245  1.44252  1.44074  1.44110  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-11  EURUSD  1.44280  1.45560  1.44080  1.45120  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-12  EURUSD  1.45120  1.45450  1.44530  1.44840  NaN       NaN   
2010-01-13  EURUSD  1.44850  1.45790  1.44570  1.45100  NaN   1.44351   
2010-01-14  EURUSD  1.45090  1.45550  1.44460  1.44990  NaN   1.44467   
2010-01-15  EURUSD  1.45000  1.45110  1.43360  1.43790  NaN   1.44344   
2010-01-17  EURUSD  1.43597  1.43655  1.43445  1.43480  NaN   1.44187   
2010-01-18  EURUSD  1.43550  1.44000  1.43340  1.43830  NaN   1.44122   
2010-01-19  EURUSD  1.43820  1.44130  1.42520  1.42870  NaN   1.43894
```

I've changed the values of the first dataframe so that it shows the numbers that were used to calculate the values of `slow_ma`.

This is my first post on Stackoverflow so just ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the dataframe for which the results are wrong? ` _(also not sure if it makes sense for `span=period` in the input)_

Comment: From my understanding the span is the formula α=2/(span+1) which is the multiplier for weighting the EMA and the span is the period I want to calculate. It can also be written as (2 / (selected time period + 1)) = (2 / (10 + 1)) = 0.1818 (18.18%)  as an example.

Comment: What are the values you expect for `slow_ma` to have (for the sample you provided) and also what value are you using for `period`?

Comment: I've changed the values of the first dataframe to show the values that were used to calculate the slow_ma, the second dataframe contains the expected outcomes. The period I used to keep the dataframes short is a **10 day period**

Answer (score 1):

> *How to calculate an exponential moving average with python **faster ?***

speeds **under `< 50 [us]`** for your sized data/period on an old 2.6 [GHz] i5 device achievable...

---

### Step 0: Get the results ( the process ) pass the Quality Assurance

Having fast but wrong data has negative value added, right?

Given you are using a "hardwired" **`.ewm()`** method, you can but re-read it's parametrisation options, if different **`dataframe['Close']`** column-processing modes are possible.

As a fast check:

```
aPV = [ 1.43247, # borrowed from dataframe['Close']
        1.44120,
        1.43650,
        1.44060, 1.43070, 1.44160, 1.44110, 1.45120, 1.44840,
        1.45100, 1.44990, 1.43790, 1.43480, 1.43830, 1.42870,
        ]
|>>> QuantFX.numba_EMA_fromPrice2( N_period     = 10,
                                   aPriceVECTOR = QuantFX.np.array( aPV )
                                   )
array([ 
        1.43247   ,
        1.43405727,
        1.4345014 ,
        1.43561024,
        1.43471747,
        1.43596884,
        1.43690178,
        1.43950145,
        1.44111937,
        1.44291585,
        1.44418569,
        1.44304284,
        1.44154414,
        1.4409543 ,
        1.43872624
        ]
      )
```

for which there are some **`~ +/- 3E-7`** numerical-representation differences from values in the first Table above ( i.e. 2 orders below the LSD ).

```
|>>> ( QuantFX.numba_EMA_fromPrice2( 10,
                                     QuantFX.np.array( aPV )
                                     )
     - QuantFX.np.array( slow_EMA_1 )# values borrowed from Table 1 above
       )

array([             nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
                    nan,
        -1.50656152e-07,
        -3.05082306e-07,
        -1.58703705e-07,
         1.42878787e-07,
         2.98719007e-07,
         2.44406460e-07
         ]
        )
```

### Step 1: Tweak the ( QA-confirmed ) processing for better speed

During this phase, a lot depends on outer context of use.

Best results could be expected from **`cythonize()`**, yet profiling may show some surprises on the fly.

Without moving the processing into the cython-code, one can get interesting speedups on global use of `float64`-s instead of `float32`-s ( got shaved off some `110 ~ 200 [us]` on similar EMA depths ), vectorised inplace assignments ( ~ 2x speedup, from `~ 100 [us]` to `~ 50 [us]` in better combined vector-memory allocation of resulting vector and its vectorised value processing ) and best, if mathematical re-formulation can help skip some just "mechanical" operations at all.

Yet, all the speedup tricks depend on used tools - if a pure **`numpy`**, or **`numpy + numba`** ( which may yield negative effects on as trivial processing as EMA out of question is - having ***not much*** mathematical " **meat** for Dr.Jackson" to actually number-crunch ) or **`cython`**-optimised solution, so profiling in the target CPU-context is a must, if best results are to get delivered.

---

> *trying to find a **faster** solution ...*

Would be interesting to update your post with a statement of what is your expected target speedup, or better a target per-call processing cost in a `[TIME]`-domain for the stated problem, on a given `[SPACE]`-domain scale of data ( `window == 10`, `aPriceVECTOR.shape[0] ~ 15` ), and if a target code-execution platform has some hardware / CPU / cache-hierarchy composition constraints or not, because building a **backtester-platform** actually **massively emphasises** any and all code-design + code-execution **inefficiencies**.

---

### Given the EMA is reasonably efficient, tools may get ~ 4x speedup

The `QuantFX` story has gone from `~ 42000 [us]` down to `~ 21000[us]` without `numba`/JIT tools just by re-formulated and memory-optimised vector processing ( Using an artificial sized workload payloads, processing a block of **`aPV[:10000]`** ).

Next, the run-time went yet down, to **`~ 10600 [us]`**, using the as-is Cpython code-base, just with a permission to auto-Cythonise, where possible, an `import`-ed code using `pyximport`:

```
pass;        import pyximport
pass;               pyximport.install( pyimport = True )
from QuantFX import numba_EMA_fromPrice2
...
```

So, can get speeds
**`~ 45 ~ 47 [us]`** for your sized data `aPV[:15]`, period = 10 on an ordinary 2.6 [GHz] i5 device.

---

If insisting on using **`pandas`** dataframe-tools and methods, your performance is principally in the hands of pandas-team, not much to do here about their design compromises, that had to be done on an ever present  dilemma between a speed and a universality.